# Extract value from beanshell extractor

Tags: regex, jmeter, beanshell

I want to get the Sessiondatakey value from URL,How to write a regular expression in JMeter?

https://localhost:9443/authenticationendpoint/consent.do?mandatoryClaims=0_Nick+Name&**sessionDataKey=ef91eee8-b226-4640-bf56-82df2a03ce78&sp=travelocitySP1**

I tried with the below regex, but its gives the default value.

```
sessionDataKey=(.+)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sessionDataKey ends with `&` so add it to regular expression:

```
sessionDataKey=(.+)&
```

Make sure the Field to check is `URL` and Template is `$1$` and Match No. is `1`